# How to add real time search with VueJS?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I want to add realtime search to find another users that are registered on my twitter clone. So, users are on backend (Firebase)

Users on [backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3Mft.png) and [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5L7M.png) of search that i want.

Here is my attempt:

```
<script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          search: "",
          users: ['Dummy', 'Users', 'From', 'Backend'],
        };
      },
      methods: {
        findUser(){
            const result = this.users.find(user => user.includes(this.search))
            console.log(result)
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a `computed` property is better here to have the "real-time" changes, and a `.filter` to get the filtered list matching `search`:

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
      users: ['Dummy', 'Users', 'From', 'Backend'],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredUsers(){
      return this.users.filter(user =>
        user.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
      );
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="search"/>{{filteredUsers}}
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, your method works, but if I write D, it shows Dummy and BackenD, that is, all the results that contain the same letters, should it be?

But thanks anyway :)

Comment: @JOKER it depends if you want case-comparison, if you do, remove ``.toLowerCase``

Answer (score 0):

For real-time search using API, you can use WATCH

Can be applied sorted on FIREBASE
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data

```
var myUserId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
var topUserPostsRef = firebase.database().ref('user-posts/' + myUserId).orderByChild('starCount')
```

There may be inconsistencies in the code, but I wanted to convey the essence

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="search"/>{{filteredUsers}}
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data() {
    return {
      search: null, 
      users: []     
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredUsers(){
      return this.users.filter(user =>
        user.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
      );
    },  
  },
  watch: {
      watchUser(search) {
       if (search) {
       this.searchPerson()
      }
    },              
 },
 methods: {  
   searchPerson() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.fetchUsers()
          .then(res => {
            this.users = normalizeResponse(res)
            this.loading = false          
          })
      },
      fetchUsers() {
        return axios({
          method: 'get',
          url: '',
          params: {        
          },
          headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
          }
        });
      },
    }
 });
```